# How to find the trajectory of stationary action of a photon

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, action

I am trying to work through a "check your understanding" question on p.393 of the textbook *From Photon to Neuron* by Nelson. The action functional *S* of a photon's trajectory is proposed to be

$S [\underline X^\mu(\xi),e(\xi)] =\frac{\hbar}{2}  \int d\xi (e^{-1}||\dot {\underline X}||^{2} )$

where $\mu$ = 0,1,2, or 3.  $\underline X^\mu$ are spacetime coordinates;
$\underline X^0$ is $ct$. The parameter $\xi$ is some index along the trajectory. The variable $e$ is described as a metric necessary so that different parameterizations of the same path give the same action. The dot denotes differentiation with respect to $\xi$ and $||\dot {\underline X}||^{2} $ is the Lorentz invariant interval $ -(c \dot t)^2 + (\dot r)^2 $.

The reader is asked to show that the equation above is stationary under any trajectory that satisfies

$0 = e^{-2} ||\dot {\underline X}||^{2}$ and

$e^{-1} \dot {\underline X} =$ constant.

It's not clear to me if the second equation is implying an Einstein summation.

Here is what I have tried: I introduced a small variation in both the spacetime coordinates and metric along a path and examined the action of this new worldline:

$S [\underline X^\mu+ \Delta \underline X^\mu,e + \Delta e] =\frac{\hbar}{2}  \int d\xi \bigl[(e +\Delta e )^{-1}||\dot {\underline X}+\Delta\dot {\underline X} ||^{2} \bigr]$

$\approx \frac{\hbar}{2}  \int d\xi  (1 -\frac{\Delta e}{e} )\bigl( ||\dot {\underline X}||^2+2 \dot {\underline X}\Delta\dot {\underline X}^{2} + ||\Delta\dot {\underline X}^{2}||\bigr)  $

I then subtracted the action of the original worldline to get

$ \Delta S \approx \frac{\hbar}{2}  \int d\xi \bigl(\frac {2\dot {\underline X}\Delta \dot X}{e}  
+\frac {{\Delta \dot X}^2}{e}  
$
$
+\frac {2 \dot X \Delta \dot X \Delta e}{e^2}
$
$
+\frac {\Delta \dot X^2 \Delta e}{e^2} $
$
+ \frac {|| \dot X||^2 \Delta e}{e^2}
\bigr)
$

I figured I could neglect terms that were second order in $\Delta$. That leaves the first and last term in the equation above. The last term must equal zero; this satifies one of the two conditions I set out to show. But shouldn't the first also have to equal zero, not a constant?

I am hoping someone can help me track down my error(s), explain if one must vary $e$ in addition to $X$, and clarify if the second condition stated above is an Einstein summation, i.e. if $ \dot {\underline X} = c \dot t - \dot r$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to express $\Delta S$ as a function of $\Delta e$ and $\Delta X$ but you have $\Delta \dot{X}$. An integration by part will fix that. Assuming the boundaries are $\xi=0$ and $\xi=1$,

$$\Delta S \propto \left[2e^{-1}\dot{X}\Delta X\right]_{\xi=0}^{\xi=1}-\int 2\frac{d}{d\xi}(e^{-1}\dot{X})\Delta X+e^{-2}\|\dot{X}\|^2\Delta e\ d\xi$$

Since $\Delta X(0)=\Delta X(1)=0$ as usual in such variational problem, you are left with the integral only, and now you can require that the factors of your variations $\Delta X$ and $\Delta e$ are zero, which gives the result you were required to find.

I do not understand your question about Einstein summation as you have no indices in the entire computation. But yes, $\left(\frac{dX}{d\xi}\right)_\mu = \frac{dX_\mu}{d\xi}$.

Comment: I do not understand why the first term in your equation for delta S is in square brackets and not an integrand. For the integration, what are you setting as u and dv?

Comment: The square bracket is the standard notation: $[u(\xi)]_0^1=u(1) - u(0)$. Then integration by part is $\int_0^1 u(\xi)\dot{v}(\xi)d\xi=[u(\xi)v(\xi)]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \dot{u}(\xi)v(\xi)d\xi$. I guess you are more used to see it written with $dv=\dot{v}d\xi$ then but the form I have written is standard in mathematics.